# Is it possible to do an unscoped preload in Golang GORM?

Tags: go-gorm

Adding Unscoped() to the call chain like this:

```
db.Unscoped().Preload("Orders").Find(&users)
```

affects the Find(), but does not affect the Preload().

The query generated for the Preload() still contains:

```
"orders"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

How can I unscope the generated preload query? I want soft-deleted rows to be fetched by Preload().

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Callback can be like this:

```
.Preload("Orders", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
   return db.Unscoped() 
}
```